# Send commands to PJSIP APP -telnet console iPhone

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, pjsip

Actually i want to build one iPhone app which will use PJSIP library.
i have downloaded latest pjsip available. and also commandline tool.

and i am successfuly able to build PJSUA app on my iPhone.and i can see Black screen with PJSIP logo and label displaying- telnet to 192.168.*.* :2323.

but i dont see any console ,where i can enter commands,as mentioned in the pjsip document.

I Just need some initial setUp help .Like how to send command etc ,if anyone can.
it will be very grateful,if you can share some experince and knowledge with me.

Answer (score 2):

I've start same things in meanwhile ago too. Just open up your cmd or terminal and type in following command:

```
telnet 192.168.1.40 2323
```

and it should be working. Good luck!

Comment: maybe will be required to install telnet, it was missing on my system